# Customizing phone number or any other String for different Locales in GWT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am trying to find the best route to get in some Custom formats I need. For example if I have a phone number 0803456765

In India it may be represented as +91 (080) 3456765
In US it may be 080-345-6765 and so on

I could keep the format in the properties file and based on locale I could pull the format and format the String. I could also have a Util class which does this for me after I identify the Locale.

But I think there might be a better  route using NumberFormat. I guess NumberFormat automatically figures out the Locale and applies a certain Pattern to the String. Can I customize this pattern ? In the sense, can I tell GWT to use my Custom pattern for the US Locale

I know we can do this

```
// Custom format
value = 12345.6789;
formatted = NumberFormat.getFormat("000000.000000").format(value);
// prints 012345.678900 in the default locale
GWT.log("Formatted string is" + formatted, null);
```

but I don't want to specify my formatting pattern as in       'NumberFormat.getFormat("000000.000000")'. I want to override the default number formats of various Locales in GWT to achieve this. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't roll your own. Google open sourced their [library](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) which you can leverage. It supports

> Parsing/formatting/validating phone numbers for all countries/regions
>   of the world.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response . I agree this is quite useful but I will have to customize this too Eg: For use phone , it shows (999) 999-9999 but we need 999-999-9999 . They have Locale based formatting in GWT but what I need is the best way to customize this .

Comment: I guess I'll go ahead and integrate this. It looks like it'll remove lot of our formatting code.